Ergodicity when the variance doesn't converge
A power law (x^(-k)) isn't ergodic for k<= 2 given that the expected value doesn't exist (nothing to converge to). However for 2<k<=3 there is a finite expected value but an infinite variance. Would the distribution be ergodic in this interval (feel free to generalise to higher momenta) given that the variance doesn't converge (fat tails) or is there another term for this?
